# How to format this numpy array in this format?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
a = [[0.04393, 0.0, 0.0], [0.04393, 0.005, 0.0], [0.04393, 0.01, 0.0],[0.04393, 0.015, 0.0]]
```

And i want to format it in this:

```
b = [((0.04393, 0.0, 0.0), ), ((0.04393, 0.005, 0.0), ), ((0.04393, 
0.01, 0.0), ), ((0.04393, 0.015, 0.0), )]
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Where did the `0.14625` come from?

Comment: Sorry, it should be the same numbers, now it is correct.

Comment: Arrays don't look like lists of lists, but in any case, it seems you want to convert an array with shape (M, N) to (M, 1, N). http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
a = [[0.04393, 0.0, 0.0], [0.04393, 0.005, 0.0], [0.04393, 0.01, 0.0],[0.04393, 0.015, 0.0]]
b = [ (tuple(a1),) for a1 in a]
```